# ITMS-90426: Invalid Swift Support

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, fastlane

ITMS-90426: Invalid Swift Support,

> Dear Developer,
>
> We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "KxSwift" 1.0.0 (58). Please correct the following issues, then upload again.
>
> ITMS-90426: Invalid Swift Support - The SwiftSupport folder is missing. Rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode and resubmit it.
>
> Best regards,
>
> The App Store Team

The pure Swift project,
Using Fastlane to package builds,
It was always OK,
Last updated Xcode13.3, and then the packaging problem occurred,
I found a lot of posts on the Internet,
Modify the ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES configuration
But it didn't work.
Who knows why?

Comment: are you able to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I just received this error when uploading an app built with Xcode 14.2 (currently the latest version of Xcode).

In my case, the problem was that I had accidentally uploaded an Adhoc build, instead of an App Store build.

Rebuilding and submitting an App Store build resolved the issue for me.